# Can't see UI elements on the scene (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a training project (Arkanoid). When bonus block is destroyed, the paddle is temporarily expended and this effect is illustrated by the timebar.
The problem is that TimeBar object is instantiated and destroyed after bonus time expires, but I can't see the time bar and the text on the scene.

So I created `LinearTimer` prefab that consists of UI Image (white bar) and UI Text ("Bonus Text"):

[Prefab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9oh7.png)

There is a script that animates the timebar in a proper way. Debug messages appear in the console correctly:

```unity
    public class TimeBar : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float maxTime = 15f;
        float timeLeft;
        Image timerBar;
    
        void Start()
        {
            timerBar = GetComponent<Image>();
            timeLeft = maxTime;
            Debug.Log("BONUS START");
        }
    
        void Update()
        {
            if (timeLeft > 0)
            {
                timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
                timerBar.fillAmount = timeLeft / maxTime;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("BONUS END");
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

Initially there are no TimeBar objects in the scene. TimeBar object is to be instantiated in Expand() method of Paddle class:

```unity
    public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] TimeBar timeBar;
        
        void Start()
        {
        }
    
        public void Expand()
        {
            Instantiate(timeBar, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, transform.Find("Game Canvas"));
    
            Vector3 newScale = new Vector3(1.5f, 1, 1);
            transform.localScale = newScale;
            
            StartCoroutine("ExpandTime");
        }
        
        private IEnumerator ExpandTime()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(15f);
            Vector3 newScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            transform.localScale = newScale;
        }
    }
```

Even when I add LinearTimer instance to the scene manually I can't see it on the scene:

[LinearTimer added to the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUDhu.jpg)

May be something's wrong with asset settings?

[Prefab asset Inspector 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjy7R.png) and
[Prefab asset Inspector 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNhtF.png)

P.S.: UI is toggled on in Layers.

Comment: Is your UI stuff a child of a Canvas? Otherwise it won't be rendered... Seems to be the case in your setup ... Make sure you Instantiate these UI items as child of a Canvas .. or if necessary you could also have a canvas for each prefab ..

Comment: That's what I tried to do in `Expand()` method by calling `Instantiate()`. My code is `Instantiate(timeBar, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, transform.Find("Game Canvas"));`. How can I fix it so the instantiated object is a child of Game Canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see the `LinearTimer` object because this object is an UI element.

UI elements are **always rendered in canvas**.

Just drag your `LinearTimer` object into `Game Canvas` object.

Edit : You should use this `GameObject.Find("Game Canvas").transform` instead of this `transform.Find("Game Canvas")`.

Comment: That's what I tried to do in `Expand()` method by calling `Instantiate()`. My code is `Instantiate(timeBar, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, transform.Find("Game Canvas"));`. How can I fix it so the instantiated object is a child of Game Canvas?